# Convert Windows/MacOS links and share them with colleagues

Tags: windows, macos, networking, smb, unc

Is there an easy solution for Windows/MacOS link conversion to share links with colleagues?

I have a windows link for e.g.:

```
\\networkshare\folder\subfolder
```

and i want to convert to:

```
smb://networkshare/folder/subfolder
```

It is very annoying to convert the link manually several times a day

With the existing applescripts I mostly miss a function or it doesn't work with all links. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way I came across is the [Linkconverter](https://apps.apple.com/app/linkconverter/id1604758881) App.
The app converts both ways:

```
smb://server/folder --> \\server\folder

\\server\folder --> smb://server/folder
```